# Export to Excel from HTML

Tags: html, .net, excel, .net-core

Is there any way to export to excel from HTML table. I have used HTML table in .NET Core application and would need to format the table with style and the the same have to export to excel.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can achieve it using [Datatables](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html) Plugin

```
<table id="example" class="display nowrap" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js'></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ]
    } );
} );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

the library `tableToExcel.517b1af9.js` is here https://github.com/linways/table-to-excel/blob/master/dist/tableToExcel.517b1af9.js

```
<script src="/tableToExcel.517b1af9.js"></script>

<script>
TableToExcel.convert(document.getElementById("idTable"));
</script>
```